# Create new table based on characters

Tags: arrays, r, regex

I have two questions.

1) I have a dataset (df) where the last column, which begins with "09", is on every other row. Like so:

```
a <- c("01+0135.","09-6999","01+0135.","09-6999")    
b <- c("02+2015.", "", "02+2015.", "")
c <- c("03+0349.","", "03+0349.", "")
d <- c("04+0537.","","04+0542.","")
e <- c("05+170.1","","05+170.1","")
f <- c("06+0.033","","06+0.384","")
g <- c("07+0.001","","07+0.395","")
h <- c("08+0.000","","08+0.000","")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)

> df

1 01+0135. 02+2015. 03+0349. 04+0537. 05+170.1 06+0.033 07+0.001 08+0.000
2 09-6999                                                               
3 01+0135. 02+2015. 03+0349. 04+0542. 05+170.1 06+0.384 07+0.395 08+0.000
4 09-6999
```

Is there a simple way to get every other row (perhaps using regex) to appear in a ninth column?

2) How do I remove the first three characters of each column (i.e. 06+) and the period at the end of each column for columns beginning with 01, 02, 03, and 04?

Comment: I get an error when attempting to run that code.

Comment: Acknowledged, it should be data.frame not as.data.frame.

Comment: Now we need to know what you expect to happen with the `""`-items when you "move" every other item in the `a`-vector to the ninth column, which is how I am interpreting your request. Do you expect the resulting dataframe to have 2 or 4 rows? To get answers without extended dialogs in comments, you should post an edit to your question with the exact output expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, you can split and recombine:

```
df1 <- df[(1:nrow(df))%%2==1,]
df2 <- df[(1:nrow(df))%%2==0,]
df1$i <- df2$a

df1
#          a        b        c        d        e        f        g        h       i
# 1 01+0135. 02+2015. 03+0349. 04+0537. 05+170.1 06+0.033 07+0.001 08+0.000 09-6999
# 3 01+0135. 02+2015. 03+0349. 04+0542. 05+170.1 06+0.384 07+0.395 08+0.000 09-6999
```

For the second issue, the simplest way might be to use `substr()` (but that's assuming that you really only want characters 4 through 7 of each, otherwise we'll want to do something with regular expressions):

```
for(i in 1:4) df1[,i] <- substr(df1[,i],4,7)

df1
#      a    b    c    d        e        f        g        h       i
# 1 0135 2015 0349 0537 05+170.1 06+0.033 07+0.001 08+0.000 09-6999
# 3 0135 2015 0349 0542 05+170.1 06+0.384 07+0.395 08+0.000 09-6999
```

Comment: I managed to get column "a" using the following: 
`a<-regmatches(df1, regexpr("[0-9]{0,0}01+[0-9]{1,4}",df1))` however, I can't seem to do this for column "b": `b<-regmatches(df1, regexpr("[0-9]{0,0}02+[0-9]{1,4}",df1))`

Comment: Found a solution. As these are based on regular intervals: `a<-substr(df1,4,7)`